# Method not defined in class error

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to use a method in a separate class and it is redlining it saying

`StringMethods does not contain definition for ParseCsvString etc`

here is the source from the code I'm building now....

```
public class Employee
{
    public static Employee Parse(string stringValue)
    {
      string[] words;
      Employee employee = new Employee();

      words = StringMethods.ParseCsvString(stringValue.Trim());
      employee.ID = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
      employee.Name = words[1];
      employee.HireDate = Date.Parse(words[2]);
      employee.Rate = double.Parse(words[3]);
      employee.Hours = Double.Parse(words[4]);

      return employee;
    }
}
```

and here is the code from the separate class that defines the parse method...

```
public class StringMethods
{
    public static string[] ParseCsvString(string stringValue)
    {
      int      i = 0;
      string[] words = null;
      Regex    regex = new Regex(@"""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]+");
      Match    matchResults = null;

      if (stringValue!=null)
      {
        stringValue = stringValue.Trim();
        matchResults = regex.Match(stringValue);
        while (matchResults.Success) 
        {
          i++;
          matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
        }
        words        = new string[i];
        matchResults = regex.Match(stringValue);
        i = 0;
        for (i=0; i<words.Length; i++) 
        {
          words[i]     = matchResults.Value.Replace("\"","");
          matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
        }
      }
      return words;
    }
}
```

when i call to `words = StringMethods.ParseCsvString(stringValue.Trim())` it says it is not defined. But it is and the DLL is current. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please show the classes where the `Parse` function and `ParseCsvString` sit. Also, are their in the same namespace? If not do you have `using NamespaceToClassWithSecondFunction`?

Comment: what is `StringMethods` is that a class or an instance

Comment: the parse function is in a class called `Employee` and the `ParseCsvString` is in a class called `LibUtil` I have the proper `Using LibUtil;` intact. they aren't in the same name space but I may attempt that to see if it will fix it.

Comment: @JonButler - they do not have to be in the same namespace. Again please show the class definition of the `ParseCsvString` and how that function sits in it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/06Y40mSi is the source for my LibUtil. And In my employee class I'm just trying to call it inside the employee class (which is inside a separate .cs file).

Comment: @JonButler Is the namespace LibUtil packaged as a separate dll or it belong to the same package (as Employee class). Also (if you are using Visual Studio) could you navigate to StringMethods class (press F12 after selecting StringMethods) and see if it includes ParseCsvString.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're referencing an older version of the Dll in your project. Are you sure you are using the current and that you build it after adding ParseCsvString function?

Comment: I've tried you scenario and it works fine for me, have you done a clean and then try build again?